# Parsing a pipe delimited json data in python

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, parsing

I am trying to parse an API response which is JSON. the JSON looks like this:

```
{
     'id': 112,
     'name': 'stalin-PC',
     'type': 'IP4Address',
     'properties': 'address=10.0.1.110|ipLong=277893412|state=DHCP Allocated|macAddress=41-1z-y4-23-dd-98|'
}
```

It's length is 1200, If i convert it I should get 1200 rows. My goal is to parse this json like below:

id      name     type       address     iplong        state         macAddress

```
112    stalin-PC IP4Address 10.0.1.110  277893412   DHCP Allocated  41-1z-y4-23-dd-98
```

I am getting the first 3 elements but having an issue in "properties" key which value is pipe delimited. I have tried the below code:

```
for network in networks:          # here networks = response.json()
    network_id = network['id']
    network_name = network['name']
    network_type = network['type']
  
    print(network_id, network_name, network_type)
```

It works file and gives me result :

```
112    stalin-PC IP4Address
```

But when I tried to parse the properties key with below code , its not working.

```
for network in networks:   
    network_id = network['id']
    network_name = network['name']
    network_type = network['type']
    for line in network['properties']:
        properties_value = line.split('|')
        network_address = properties_value[0]

    print(network_id, network_name, network_type, network_address )`
```

How can I parse the pipe delimited properties key? Would anyone help me please.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str`  methods

**Ex:**

```
network = {
        'id': 112,
        'name': 'stalin-PC',
        'type': 'IP4Address',
        'properties': 'address=10.0.1.110|ipLong=277893412|state=DHCP Allocated|macAddress=41-1z-y4-23-dd-98'
}

for n in network['properties'].split("|"):
    key, value = n.split("=")
    print(key, "-->", value)
```

**Output:**

```
address --> 10.0.1.110
ipLong --> 277893412
state --> DHCP Allocated
macAddress --> 41-1z-y4-23-dd-98
```